# How to resolve Gradle plugin dependency?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to install Eclipse integration Gradle from

http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle

in order to create LibGdx project in Eclipse.

But there is a dependency issue where I am stuck at and not able to understand the error.

Below is the error stack in eclipse while trying to install the Gradle plugin.

Software being installed: Spring UAA Integration (optional) 3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa.feature.feature.group 3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Spring UAA Integration 3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa 3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE) requires 'package com.google.protobuf 0.0.0' but it could not be found

**UPDATE:**
http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (latest release) did not work.
But,
http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/gradle (latest milestone build) worked!

Comment: If you are having problems with gradle, I suggest using the old setup https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-old-setup-ui , i love it, really. The project is smaller on disk, and is loading almost instant.

Answer (score 11):

The author has made this question easy to answer by posting the answer himself. So I will swoop in and take the easy points.

Use:
http://dist.springsource.com/milestone/TOOLS/gradle (latest milestone build)

because the requirements (Spring UAA Integration 3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE) are included in the aforementioned add-on.

http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle (latest release) did not work.

because the requirements (Spring UAA Integration 3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE) are NOT (I repeat NOT!!) included in the aforementioned add-on.