# Eclipse Gradle plugin not installing

Tags: java, android, spring, eclipse-plugin, gradle

I have been trying to add Gradle plugin for eclipse but it shows error.  Any help would be appreciated.

check screenshot http://io.putul.me/Ha5Jbc

The detail box has the following information.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring UAA Integration (optional) 3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa.feature.feature.group 3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Spring UAA Integration 3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa 3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE) requires 'package org.springframework.uaa.client 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring UAA Integration (optional) 3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa.feature.feature.group 3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE)
    To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa [3.6.1.201408250654-RELEASE]
```

Comment: This is related to Spring UAA. This issue is well explained in the SOO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835070/how-to-resolve-gradle-plugin-dependancy

Answer (score 0):

the same problem happened to me but after updating eclipse to version 4.4 - put in **help** >> **install new software** http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4 - the gradle installed correctly